# AutoCompleteTextView don't filter text inside of brackets

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have written the code for AutoCompleteTextView as follows

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteText);
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contries_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_list_item,countries);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected item is :"+item ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The array list i provided is

```
<string-array name="contries_array">
    <item>Afganistan</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>New Zee Land</item>
    <item>New Yourk</item>
    <item>Africa</item>
    <item>228(BRAZIL_STATION-AIRPORT)</item>
    <item>228(AIRPORT-BRAZIL_STATION)</item>
    <item>228A(BRAZIL_STATION-LA)</item>
</string-array>
```

It works fine when i search for 'af' or 'in' or '22' it then shows me the filtered list, but when i search for 'br' then i expect it to show me the last three options from the array as filtered. But its not showing, it just shows those three option when i search '22'.

Help me out, Thanks in adavance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the search criteria of auto complete text view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472809/how-to-change-the-search-criteria-of-auto-complete-text-view)

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the filter for ArrayAdapters is to search the beginning of words (separated by space). You will need to implement a Filter which uses `contains`

Look at the implementation for ArrayFilter at the bottom of [this source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)